# How to Close the opentip(plugin) when click on anywhere on the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using "Opentip" plugin for the tooltip. I am trying to close the open tip on click on anywhere on the window.
This is my code on open the opentip (click on open and close)

```
new Opentip($("#dcr-sku-tooltip"), toolTipData, '', {
                stem: true,
                tipJoint: 'top right',
                offset: [3, 10],
                stemLength: 4,
                fixed: true,
                showOn: 'click',
                hideOn: 'click',
                style: "dashBoardStyle"
            });
```

Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: can you create a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know "Opentip" but you can define an onClick event at your page outer element (if you let it bubble) that forces to close the tooltip using display: none or height: 0px or whatever effect you want for the tooltip ID/Class